# React-select-pagination not fetching data on scroll

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, pagination, react-select

I am using react-select with more than 20,000 options fetched from the database via Node API.
Page was not even loading .
Now, I added "react-select-async-pagination".
But the data is fetched once only.

```
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";
import LoadOptions from "./LoadOptions";
import { AsyncPaginate } from "react-select-async-paginate";

const TooManySelect = () => {
  
  const [value, onChange] = useState(null);
  return (
    <div className="Select-options">
      <label>Pdt code</label>
      <AsyncPaginate
        defaultOptions
        value={value}
        loadOptions={LoadOptions}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
     
    </div>
  );
};

export default TooManySelect;
```

LoadOptions : Here is the api call. I am passing the count of the last row fetched every time via "prevLast" so that I can use the OFFSET prevLast ROWS inside database query.

```
import { useState } from "react";

const sleep = (ms) =>
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve();
    }, ms);
  });

const baseurl = "http://localhost:5000/api";

const LoadOptions = async (search, prevOptions) => {
  const [prevLast, setPrevLast] = useState(0);
  const [pdtOpt, setPdtOpt] = useState([]);
  
  await sleep(1000);

  const response = await fetch(`${baseurl}/pdt/${prevLast}`);
  const pList = await response.json();
  const pdtList = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < pList.length; i++) {
    pdtList.push({ label: pList[i].pdtno, value: pList[i].pdtno });
  }
  setPdtOpt(pdtList);
  setPrevLast(pList.length);

  return {
    options: pdtList,
    hasMore: true
  };
};

export default LoadOptions;
```

Here is my codesandbox link.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-paginate-test-tob90j

My question is : How can we access thousands of (select) options from DB without page freeze?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this link while googleing.

https://blog.saeloun.com/2022/03/03/infinite-scroll-with-pagination.html#using-lazy-loading-and-pagination

It helped me came to a perfect solution.
So my current code goes like this
(Made only a few changes from the code given in the above link).

Select component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import SelectWrapper from "./SelectWrapper";

const baseurl = "http://localhost:5000/api";

function MainSelect() {
  const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState("");

  const [pageNo, setPageNo] = useState(0);
  const [hasNextPage, setHasNextPage] = useState(true);
  const [isNextPageLoading, setIsNextPageLoading] = useState(false);

  const loadOptions = async (page) => {
    try {
      //  console.log(`Page ${page}`);
      const size = 50;
      setIsNextPageLoading(true);
      const data = await fetch(`${baseurl}/pdt/${page}/${size}`);
      const pList = await data.json();
      const pdtList = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < pList.length; i++) {
        pdtList.push({ label: pList[i].pdtno, value: pList[i].pdtno });
      }

      setOptions(pdtList);
      setIsNextPageLoading(false);
      setHasNextPage(pdtList.length < 500);
      setPageNo(page);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
  console.log(options);

  const loadNextPage = async () => {
    await loadOptions(pageNo + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div className="dropdown">
      <div className="dropdown">
        <div className="label">
          <label>Pdt</label>
        </div>
        <SelectWrapper
          value={selectedOption}
          placeholder="Select"
          isClearable
          hasNextPage={hasNextPage}
          isNextPageLoading={isNextPageLoading}
          options={options}
          loadNextPage={loadNextPage}
          onChange={(selected) => setSelectedOption(selected)}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MainSelect;
```

SelectWrapper that carries out the Virtualization part:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { FixedSizeList as List } from "react-window";
import InfiniteLoader from "react-window-infinite-loader";
import Select from "react-select";
import AutoSizer from "react-virtualized-auto-sizer";

const SelectWrapper = (props) => {
  const {
    hasNextPage,
    isNextPageLoading,
    options,
    loadNextPage,
    placeholder,
    onChange,
    value,
  } = props;

  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState(value);

  useEffect(() => {
    setSelectedOption(value);
  }, [value]);

  const itemCount = hasNextPage ? options.length + 1 : options.length;

  const loadMoreItems = isNextPageLoading ? () => {} : loadNextPage;

  const isItemLoaded = (index) => !hasNextPage || index < options.length;

  const MenuList = ({ children }) => {
    const childrenArray = React.Children.toArray(children);
    const Item = ({ index, style, ...rest }) => {
      const child = childrenArray[index];    
      return (
        <div
          className="drop-down-list"
          style={{
            borderBottom: "1px solid rgb(243 234 234 / 72%)",
            display: "flex",
            alignItems: "center",
            ...style,
          }}
          onClick={() => handleChange(options[index])}
          {...rest}
        >
          {isItemLoaded(index) && child ? child : `Loading...`}
        </div>
      );
    };
    return (
      <AutoSizer disableHeight>
        {({ width }) => (
          <InfiniteLoader
            isItemLoaded={(index) => index < options.length}
            itemCount={itemCount}
            loadMoreItems={loadMoreItems}
          >
            {({ onItemsRendered, ref }) => (
              <List
                className="List"
                height={150}
                itemCount={itemCount}
                itemSize={35}
                onItemsRendered={onItemsRendered}
                ref={ref}
                width={width}
                overscanCount={4} 
              >
                {Item}
              </List>
            )}
          </InfiniteLoader>
        )}
      </AutoSizer>
    );
  };

  const handleChange = (selected) => {
    console.log("test");
    onChange(selected);
  };

  return (
    <Select
      placeholder={placeholder}
      components={{ MenuList }}
      value={selectedOption}
      options={options}
      {...props}
    />
  );
};
export default SelectWrapper;
```

For anyone who needs the same, I have updated the codepen as well.
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-paginate-test-tob90j